# Using bundler with "--path vendor", why are gems specified with ":git" not locally vendored?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, vendor

I'm using bundler and have a `Gemfile` that looks like this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra', '1.3.1'
gem 'httparty'
# ...etc...
gem 'my_custom_gem', :git => 'git@github.com:me/my_custom_gem.git'
```

When I run `bundle install` it fetches the necessary gems, including my custom gem, and installs them in the system gem directory. So far, so good. However, an issue arises when I try to vendor them into a project-local directory. When I run

```
bundle install --path vendor
```

It creates the "vendor" directory in my project root and installs all the regular gems there. So I see directories like

```
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/httparty-0.8.1
...etc...
```

But it does not vendor the gem specified with a 'git' parameter. I expect to see but do not see anything like

```
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/my_custom_gem-1.0.0
```

It continues to use the system-installed version of this gem. Any explanation for this? Any clean way to get this custom gem vendored as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not supported right now, hopefully coming in Bundler 1.1:

https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/67

For now you'll have to do:

```
cd vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/
git clone git://github.com/foo/foo.git
```

or similar